# Where can I ask about Viber and WhatsApp?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about WhatsApp and Viber. Where can I ask about them on the Stack Exchange network? I'm lost with the multitude of sites.

> My Viber was originally on a British number which is now inactive (and I'm in different country). The story became complicated when I bought a new phone. Is there a way to transfer the old Viber to the new phone without the need to call to the British number which is already inactive as mentioned above?

Comment: Depends on what type of questions. That's why you should include the example question

Comment: You can research [Viber's knowledge base like this](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/2544156#switch%20devices)

Comment: I've seen it but it couldn't help me. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your phone OS. Pick the appropriate one among:

- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com) - {[viber](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viber)} {[whatsapp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp-messenger)}
- [Ask Different (Apple)](https://apple.stackexchange.com) - {[whatsapp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp.app)}
- [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com) - {[viber](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viber)} {[whatsapp](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp)}